# html5 geolocation with fusion tables

Tags: html

Can anyone help me? I cant insert the geolocation in this code.
Is it possible to use a button to search for update the current location?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.532616713472365, -8.901311618652244),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col4",
        from: "xxxxx",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });
```

Comment: Just call `getCurrentPosition` and pass the result to whichever function you like? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Please try this sample. https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ I got this link from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation#try-it-yourself